# Sort a dictionary by length of the value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'a':[1,3], 'b':[3,4,5,6], 'c':[1], 'd':[1,2,3] }
```

I want to make a smaller, new dictionary with the top two key:value pairs, sorted by the `len` of the lists in value.  So in this case, I want:

```
newd = {'b':[3,4,5,6], 'd':[1,2,3] }
```

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868457/python-sorting-dictionary-by-length-of-values) but got this error:

```
NameError: global name 'd' is not defined
```

Comment: Please post exactly how you tried to implement the other solution. It looks *exactly* like what you wanted, so you must have made a mistake when you adapted the code. When I use the other code it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't adapt the code.  I just copy and pasted from the answer.

Comment: Well, I did as well and it works for me. See http://codepad.org/RyobPnHY. Did you copy the `>>>` as well by any chance? As it is, this question is just a duplicate. We cannot help you to learn to copy&paste code properly.

Comment: "top two key:value pairs, sorted by the `len` of the lists in value" - you know dicts have no order, right? If you just want the key-value pairs with the top two longest values, you're fine, but if you want the dict to be sorted by value length, you're going to have problems.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't care about the order in the new dictionary, just that they contain the top n key:values pairs according to length of value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to sort the items according to length of value, and then create a dictionary from the last two items.

```
sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda item : len(item[1]))
newd = dict(sorted_items[-2:])
```

Comment: I'd argue that passing `reverse=true` to `sorted` is more performant than reversing the whole list afterwards. It's probably also helpful if you explain what `[::-1]` means exactly.

Comment: Or slice off the last two `dict(sorted_items[-2:])`

Comment: @Felix King: It probably is. Adjusted the code to just slice the last two anyway.

Comment: @gnibbler, I was making that edit similar to what you suggested, but reversal is irrelevant if you just slice the last two.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a job for `heapq`:

```
big_items = heapq.nlargest(2, d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
newd = dict(big_items)
```

The advantage of `heapq` over `sorted` is that this provides an O(N) time complexity whereas `sorted` will yield an O(NlogN) time complexity.  For small dicts, this probably doesn't matter much.  `sorted` may even be faster due to a more optimized implementation, but for big dicts, this might actually buy you a significant speedup.

---

(on python2.x, you can use `d.iteritems()` instead of `d.items()`)

Comment: +1 although `sorted` is probably _faster_ most of the time.

Comment: @gnibbler -- That depends on the size of the dictionary.

Comment: I know about the big-O, but the constant is quite large in this case, so it takes a while before the log overtakes it.

Comment: @gnibbler -- Yeah, I added a caveat in there about using `sorted` for smaller dicts.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and showing me something new as well (`heapq`).  My dict has 40,000 entries and I want to extract 5,000.  I'm guessing this is considering relatively small?

Comment: @mchangun -- Not sure.  The best thing to do would be to `timeit` to find out.