# sort values of lists inside dictionary based on length of characters

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, sorting, dictionary

```
d = {'A': ['A11117',
 '33465'
 '17160144',
 'A11-33465',
 '3040',
 'A11-33465 W1',
 'nor'], 'B': ['maD', 'vern', 'first', 'A2lRights']}
```

I have a dictionary `d` and I would like to sort the values based on length of characters. For instance, for key `A` the value `A11-33465 W1` would be first because it contains 12 characters followed by `'A11-33465'` because it contains 9 characters etc. I would like this output:

```
d = {'A': ['A11-33465 W1', 
' A11-33465',
 '17160144',
 'A11117',
 '33465',
 '3040',
 'nor'], 
'B': ['A2lRights',
'first',
'vern',
'maD']}
```

(I understand that dictionaries are not able to be sorted but I have examples below that didn't work for me but the answer contains a dictionary that was sorted)

I have tried the following

[python sorting dictionary by length of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868457/python-sorting-dictionary-by-length-of-values)

```
print(' '.join(sorted(d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]), reverse=True)))
```

[Sort a dictionary by length of the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464368/sort-a-dictionary-by-length-of-the-value/20464424#20464424)

```
sorted_items = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda item : len(item[1]))
newd = dict(sorted_items[-2:])
```

[How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

```
import operator
sorted_x = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

But they both do not give me what I am looking for.

How do I get my desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **not** sorting the `dict`, you are sorting the lists inside it. The simplest will be a loop that sorts the lists in-place:

```
for k, lst in d.items():
    lst.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
```

This will turn `d` into:

```
{'A': ['3346517160144', 'A11-33465 W1', 'A11-33465', 'A11117', '3040', 'nor'], 
 'B': ['A2lRights', 'first', 'vern', 'maD']}
```

If you want to keep the original data intact, use a comprehension like:

```
sorted_d = {k: sorted(lst, key=len, reverse=True) for k, lst in d.items()}
```